# Font Family Does Not Change

Tags: fabricjs

I am using fabricjs. I let the user change the font family. However, these changes are not reflected on the canvas after they are made. I need to change the width or height of the text box. When I make this change, the textbox on the canvas is rendered and the new font appears. How can I solve this problem?

`canvas.renderAll()` doesn't solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Are you preloading your fonts? See here for an example of using a font preloader with fabricjs http://fabricjs.com/loadfonts

Comment: Take also in consideration in 4.3 there was a bug, fixed with 4.3.1 and the set method on text wasn't working on some properties.

Comment: Thanks friends. Upgrading Fabric to 4.3.1 eliminated many text problems. I did the font family problem by using load operations. I finished the font installation process and added the answer below. Thank for your support. melchiar  & AndreaBogazzi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser loads a font only after using it in the DOM. So you need to install fonts before using them.

You can use -> https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Include this in your application and ensure that fonts are added to the DOM during the installation process.